# On Hiding soft button Navigation bar, status bar keeps uncovered space on right

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to hide soft navigation bar in android. But when it hides, the status bar gets blank space on the right.

Screen with shown Navigation bar:

[image: Screen with shown Navigation bar]

Screen with hidden navigation bar:

[image: Screen with hidden navigation bar]

Screen with hidden navigation bar and swiped down the status bar

[image: Screen with hidden navigation bar and swiped down the status bar]

I want to cover the space by the status bar when soft-navigation bar is hidden

Comment: It looks like a bad implementation from manufacturer side. I'm not sure though!

Comment: Definitely bad system interface implementation. +1 to Somesh